# Multiple aggregations in Data.table

Tags: r, data.table

So a pretty common pattern is this:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=category]
```

which will sum a subset grouped by the category.

But what if I want to sum col a but mean col b?  (using the .SD)

Comment: DT[ , by = category, .(sum(a), mean(b))]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a pattern in column names, I'll use iris dataset as an example, and the pattern will be the word 'Width'.

```
dt=as.data.table(iris)
dt[,
   lapply(.SD,
          function(X)
            ifelse(grepl("Width",deparse(substitute(X))),sum(X),mean(X))
          ),by=Species]
```